# Ribbon interface on Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, interface

I am new to Ubuntu,
and i recently learn about ribbon interface on libreoffice
so i make a try on it
but somehow, the interface indeed change into ribbon, but some of the menu is cut..
and the themes change to dark themes for no reason which really hard to see it..
[image: dark theme and cut menu]

i am on libreoffice 5.4.2.2 and Ubuntu 17.10
any solution for it?
thanks in advance

Comment: I think there is no solution based on the latest version, so I think you will make do with the current state!

Comment: Quite sad to learn there is no solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you're searching for is how to restore your LibreOffice to its original look with the old Toolbar layout, then follow this steps:

1. Click on the upper left icon of LibreOffice.
   [image]
2. A menu will appear, choose the option "Menubar".
   [image]
3. With this you can enable the old menu
   [image]
4. Go to `View` --> `Toolbar Layout` --> `Default`
   [image]
5. After choosing that option, you will recover your old LibreOffice.
   [image]
6. Finally, you can press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, this will open the "Options" menu, where you can disable the "experimental features".
   [image]
7. And reboot.

   [image]

**NOTE:** If you're using Groupedbar Full Ribbon Layout, see the image below, it's easier, just move to the left the LibreOffice Window and expand it, then you will see the other buttons:

[image]

Hope this helps, good luck!